# Meaning of a set of measure zero

Tags: measure-theory, partial-differential-equations

I have problem with the meaning of a set of measure zero in the following sentence:

> The set of initial data with the property $X$ that gives rise to some solutions is of measure zero in the space of all initial data with the property $X$.

Is this related to measure theory? If yes, how and what does it mean?

Comment: Consider that, under the normal concept of "size" or "measure" (one that is consistent with our notion of length), any finite set of real numbers is of measure zero. It just means that you can cover the entire measure zero set with a collection of tiny intervals whose total length is extremely small (arbitrarily small). A set of infinite size can also be measure zero though, for example, the rational numbers are a set of measure zero.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, this is a term from measure theory.  I encountered it while studying Hausdorff and Lebesgue measure, but it can be used with other measures as well.

A set with measure zero means just that -- it has no effective value when measured.  A canonical example with Lebesgue measure is the [Cantor set](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/CantorSet.html).  While it is easy to define the measure of the interval $[0,1]$ on the number line to have measure 1, the Cantor set removes one-third of that interval in the first iteration, and one third of each segment in following iterations, such that with each iteration, the measure gets smaller, and the limit of such activities is that the measure of the Cantor set is zero.  This is not to say that the Cantor set is empty; indeed, the Cantor set has infinitely many endpoints that remain even after infinite iterations.

What I believe the quote is trying to suggest, then, is that the initial data that gives rises to your solutions exists, but the probability of selecting it at random is zero.  To use another wording from measure theory, the set of all initial data gives rise to your solutions *almost nowhere*.

Comment: Thanks! It helps to understand the quote. I can't figure out how the comment of @jdods could be related to my quote.

Comment: @RieMann He said the same thing that I did, only from the other direction.  I stated that you could take away enough from the line segment to have a measure of zero and still have points left; he pointed out that if you start with a few finite points, they each have a length of zero, so their total length is zero.  If you keep adding points, you can add countably infinitely many and still have a length of zero.

Comment: I see! I misinterpreted it. Back to my quote, is this jargon usual in the context of PDE, for example?

Comment: When using Lebesgue integrals instead of Riemann integrals, the jargon of "almost everywhere" and "almost nowhere" is very common, falling back on measure to explain what it means when one needs to be formal.  From that context, it can show up in any context that involves integration or countably vs uncountably infinite sets, depending on how familiar the author is with this type of measure.